# App in background the soft keyboard not appear while notification come

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an issue on softkeyboard opening in android.I have one activity and a fragment , fragment containing and edittext when notification come i want to inflate the fragment .

the problem i am facing when app is in background and notification come then my softkeyboard not appear.

i am using interface , in the fragment , when fragment appear i set the interface and pass to the activity.

here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public void softkeyBoard(final EditText editText, boolean isFocusable) {
        Log.e("@@@isFocusable",""+isFocusable+"---->>"+editText.isFocused());
        //InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(isFocusable){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }else{
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call

```
editText.requestFocus()
```

To display the keyboard

Comment: earlier under if condition i have done like this only but it's not working